# Can I use two events in a single line?

Tags: jquery

I want an action to take place on keyup as well as on change.

The statement below works perfectly for the keyup event.  I want to duplicate it on change.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

```
$("#YourName").keyup(function() {
    ThisValue = $(this).attr("value");
    if (ThisValue.length > 0) {
        ThisValue = "<b>From:</b><br /> " + ThisValue;
        $("#YourNameValid").html(ThumbsUp);
    } else {
        ThisValue = "";
        $("#YourNameValid").html("");
    }
    $("#YourNameText").html(ThisValue);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function yourEventHandler() {
    ThisValue = $(this).attr("value");
    if (ThisValue.length > 0) {
        ThisValue = "<b>From:</b><br /> " + ThisValue;
        $("#YourNameValid").html(ThumbsUp);
    } else {
        ThisValue = "";
        $("#YourNameValid").html("");
    }
    $("#YourNameText").html(ThisValue);
}

$("#YourName").keyup(yourEventHandler).change(yourEventHandler);
```

The above uses a common function passed as the event handler to each event. Alternatively, you can use `bind` (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)), which accepts multiple events as the first parameter.

Comment: I just implemented this answer.  It works perfectly for me.  Thanks for being so quick and clear.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
$("#YourName").bind('keyup change', function() {
    ThisValue = $(this).val();
    if (ThisValue.length > 0) {
        ThisValue = "<b>From:</b><br /> " + ThisValue;
        $("#YourNameValid").html(ThumbsUp);
    } else {
        ThisValue = "";
        $("#YourNameValid").html("");
    }
    $("#YourNameText").html(ThisValue);
});
```

Comment: I tend to not use "bind".  It seems to be more old school.  It certainly does work perfectly though.  Thanks!!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using bind sepecially in the cases when u want to attach same handler for multiple events. Thanks anyways.